# Post Content on Google+ Business Page - SEO

Tags: seo

Is it a good idea to directly post content on google+ business page instead of sharing (adding) the link of a blog written by us?

Right now, the blog cannot be setup in the website. So, will posting informative content on google+ business page will be a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear

Maybe suggest to your client its done on a sub domain and even hosted elsewhere so blog.yourdomain.com
This have a couple of benefits, firstly **google** will know the blog is part of the site so credit it with the new content.
But one other thing is that if the blog is hosted elsewhere should there be a problem with the main site for what ever reason the blog would still function giving you a way to communicate with your users.
Its always nice to have a fallback solution and maybe offering them that might help.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Posting content to G+ is good idea. But you have more control on your own blog. Let's imagine some scenarios: 1. Google shuts down Google+. 2. Your content don't meets Google policy.